# How do i add the class i had before to my mainactivity again?

Tags: android, android-studio

In the mainactivity I have

```
import static com.web_server.webserver.TextToSpeechServer.*;
```

TextToSpeechServer is not exist.
But I have the class code:
What I did is creating from mainactivity new java class named it TextToSpeechServer and added this code instead the created one:

```
package com.web_server.webserver;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Map;

public class TextToSpeechServer extends NanoHTTPD {
    public TextToSpeechServer() {
        super(8080);
    }

    @Override public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
        Method method = session.getMethod();
        String uri = session.getUri();
        System.out.println(method + " '" + uri + "' ");

        String msg = "<html><body><h1>Hello server</h1>\n";
        Map<String, String> parms = session.getParms();

        if (parms.get("username") == null)
            msg +=
                    "<form action='?' method='get'>\n" +
                            "  <p>Your name: <input type='text' name='username'></p>\n" +
                            "</form>\n";
        else
            msg += "<p>Hello, " + parms.get("username") + "!</p>";

        msg += "</body></html>\n";

        return new Response(msg);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerRunner.run(TextToSpeechServer.class);
    }
}
```

But i'm getting errors:

NanoHTTPD not exist

8080 object() in object cannot be applied to (int)

@Override Method does not override method from it's superclass

IHTTPSession not exist

getMethod not exist

getUri not exist

getParms not exist

And at bottom: ServerRunner also not exist

Answer (score 1):

In your import statement remove .*

```
import static com.web_server.webserver.TextToSpeechServer;
```

There is nothing after TextToSpeechServer